# Skip lock screen automatically after pressing the power button when app is in the foreground

Tags: java, android

I have been trying for a while to achieve this with no luck.
My app is a GPS tracker for hikers. Users need to look at the map very often, so I want them to be able to press the power button to turn off the screen and then to be able to bring it back when they press it again so they can save battery.

I know it has to be possible, because applications such us Google Maps and Activity Zone skip the lock screen when you do that.

I found these two solutions online but they didn't work for me. The lock mode selected (pattern, PIN, fingerprint) always shows up. I also read by some people that they are deprecated.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

OR

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire();

KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
```

Anybody knows how I can do this?

Comment: _"I also read by some people"_. Don't rely on "some people", just look up [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html).

Comment: Did you actually check the link you posted? It also says there that it's deprecated.

Comment: I did, but you seem to have missed the point I was trying to make: rather than going by what "some people" have said and not being sure about something, just look it up in the official documentation.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help at all. You don't provide any extra information and you were kind of rude. Just try to help and don't quote things that you don't like. And it seems that you also probably downvoted my question. It's really sad what this site has turned into.